# What's the equivalent of "lateral view explode" for Snowflake?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to convert some spark SQL to Snowflake:

Spark:
select map (
'01_dc_res',status_01_dc_res_sec,
'02_sent_to_dc',status_02_sent_to_dc_sec,
'03_ready_for_backroom_pick_store', status_03_ready_for_backroom_pick_store_sec) as map1
from t
lateral view explode(map1) abc as mapped_column

Here's a picture of how it looks using the Spark SQL in Hive:

[image: how it looks in Hive]

Here's how it looks in the raw data:
[image: raw table]

Snowflake: ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm basically looking for a way to pivot the data so there are more rows and less columns.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example e.g. some source data and how you want the result to be strctured

Comment: @NickW thanks just added some pics to give a better idea

Comment: The pics left me more confused than I was before seeing them. Can you paste some code and an explanation?

Comment: I concur - very confused! Please let us know what your starting data is, the code/logic to transform it and what it should look like at the end of the process

Comment: my apologies I may have confused myself as well, please check the latest edit and let me know if it's more clear, thank you @NickW

Comment: my apologies I may have confused myself as well, please check the latest edit and let me know if it's more clear, thank you @FelipeHoffa

Comment: OK - so your raw data is a single column with dates in it. You still haven't explained what your target dataset needs to look like and what the logic is (expressed in English rather than Spark code) to convert from your raw data to that target structure

Answer (score 0):

Use unpivot function. Both have the same functionality.

Ex: unpivot(val for key in (status_01_dc_res_sec, status_02_sent_to_dc_sec, status_03_ready_for_backroom_pick_store_sec))

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Eg: unpivot(val for key in (status_01_dc_res_sec, status_02_sent_to_dc_sec, status_03_ready_for_backroom_pick_store_sec))

Answer (score 0):

Use flatten function to explode compounded values into multiple rows. Please refer to their docs for the exact details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten